# Реализация SOAP клиент на PHP

Tags: php, soap

Есть сервис, с ним необходимо работать по SOAP. В упор не могу понять как построить SOAP запрос. WSDL есть, пример запроса в XML есть. Трудность вызывает именно понимание создание объекта запроса, и передача его в soap клиент.
Пример запроса:

```
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <ProcessRequest xmlns="http://loyalty.manzanagroup.ru/loyalty.xsd">
            <request>
                <OrderRequest ChequeType="Soft">
                    <RequestID>ORDER_2019_401</RequestID>
                    <OrderOperationType>Calc</OrderOperationType>
                    <OperationType>Sale</OperationType>
                    <DateTime>2022-06-24T15:22:05</DateTime>
                    <Organization>abracadabra</Organization>
                    <BusinessUnit>abracadabra</BusinessUnit>
                    <POS>abracadabra</POS>
                    <Card>
                        <CardNumber>abracadabra</CardNumber>
                    </Card>
                    <Number>s001</Number>
                    <Summ>21100.00</Summ>
                    <Discount>0.000</Discount>
                    <SummDiscounted>21100.00</SummDiscounted>
                    <PaidByBonus>0.00</PaidByBonus>
                    <Item>
                        <PositionNumber>1</PositionNumber>
                        <Article>aptos1</Article>
                        <Price>1000.00</Price>
                        <Quantity>1.000</Quantity>
                        <Summ>1000.00</Summ>
                        <Discount>0.000</Discount>
                        <SummDiscounted>1000.00</SummDiscounted>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <PositionNumber>2</PositionNumber>
                        <Article>aptos2</Article>
                        <Price>10000.00</Price>
                        <Quantity>2.00</Quantity>
                        <Summ>20000.00</Summ>
                        <Discount>0.000</Discount>
                        <SummDiscounted>20000.00</SummDiscounted>
                    </Item>
                    <Item>
                        <PositionNumber>3</PositionNumber>
                        <Article>aptos3</Article>
                        <Price>100.00</Price>
                        <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
                        <Summ>100.00</Summ>
                        <Discount>0.000</Discount>
                        <SummDiscounted>100.00</SummDiscounted>
                    </Item>
                </OrderRequest>
            </request>
            <orgName>LoyaltyTest</orgName>
        </ProcessRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Что сейчас я сделал:

```
    try {
    // Создание SOAP-клиента
    $options = array(
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'exceptions' => true,
        'trace' => 1,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'login' => '******',
        'password' => '******',
        'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
        'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
    );
    $soapClient = new SoapClient("http://mlweb56.manzanagroup.ru:8534/POSProcessing.asmx?WSDL", $options);
    #Вот как дальше работать с $soapClient
} catch (SoapFault $exception) {
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Доку на PHP.NET прочитал но понимание не пришло.

Answer (score 0):

Далее нужно просто вызвать у клиента функцию, к которой хотите обратиться и передать ей данные(список функций с форматом запроса/ответа должен быть в документации к api). В xml клиент сам их преобразует.

Пример:

```
$soapClient->$needFunction($data)
```

Конкретно в вашем случае это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
$response = $soapClient->OrderRequest([
'RequestID' => 'ORDER_2019_401',
'OrderOperationType' => 'Calc',
// и далее по списку
])
```

Конкретный рабочий пример:

Берём API http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx

```
try
{
    // Создание SOAP-клиента
    $options    = [
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'exceptions' => true,
        'trace' => 1,
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'login' => '******',
        'password' => '******',
        'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
        'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
    ];
    $soapClient = new SoapClient('http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL', $options);
    $response = $soapClient->Add(['intA' => 1,'intB' => 2]);
    var_dump($response); // 'AddResult' => int 3
}
catch(SoapFault $exception)
{
    echo $exception->getMessage();
}
```

Описание функций и их названия по этой же ссылке.
Я использовал функцию Add, она первая в списке:
[image: Список функций]

Если кликнем на неё перейдём на подробное описание(http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?op=Add)
и там видим опять же название функции и требуемые параметры:
[image: Пример описания функции]

Add - название функции

Требуемые параметры:

```
<intA>int</intA>
<intB>int</intB>
```

Которые мы передаём в качестве ассоциативного массива в аргумент функции.

По похожей схеме, скорее всего, получится определить название функции и параметры и в вашем API.

Comment: Я пробывал сделать так но я получаю ошибку: Function ("OrderRequest") is not a valid method for this service

Comment: Конкретно такое название функции я использовал для примера. В вашем случае название функции нужно брать из документации к API. 
Конкретный пример добавлю в ответ